# Is this grammatical: 彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ。

Tags: grammar

I was about to ask a question but I can't without first confirming,

Is this sentence:

```
彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ。
```

grammatically correct, and mean:

```
He is a movie star and also a politician.
```

==
<sup>Follow-up question here: [Why does replacing だ to である changes the meaning of a the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/why-does-replacing-to-changes-the-meaning-of-a-the-sentence)</sup>

Comment: The correct formation is 〜でもある, not 〜もだ (which means something else).

Comment: is it true that the sentence in the title although grammatical, means something like "he is a star, (that) politician is also a star" ?

Comment: "He's a movie star as well as a politician."

Comment: I think it's ok "彼は映画スターとともに、政治家もである。"

Comment: @rdb wait do you mean that 彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ correctly means "He is a movie star and also a politician." ? (thus contradicting Zhen Lin)

Comment: @Pacerier: 〜もだ for me means something like 〜もそうだ. 「行くの？僕もだ。」 ‘You're going? Me too.’ So your sentence seems malformed to me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get what your sentence in the comment meant. The corrected sentence means "He's a movie star as well as a politician." The original sounds more like you're celebrity-spotting at an event. "He's a movie star - Oh, there's a politician too!"

Comment: This exchange got me to wondering: could one say 「彼は映画スター兼政治家だ。」?

Comment: 彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ means “He is a movie star, and a politician is a movie star, too,” which is a strange thing to say and not what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that `だ` is the contracted form of `である`.`で` has to be attached to a noun. You can't leave it behind `も` as `もである`. So the correct way of inserting `も` will be:

> 彼は政治家でもある

You might be wondering whether `で` before `も` can be omitted. Only arguments can have the (case) particle omitted before `は` or `も`. In this case, the noun `政治家` is a predicate, so you cannot omit `で` before `も`.

Comment: ok just to confirm, you are saying 彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ。 is grammatically wrong because a もだ can never be together. and so (regardless of context,) 僕もだ。is also grammatically wrong because a もだ can never be togerther?

Comment: With `僕もだ`, `僕` is an argument, so there is an omitted case particle before `も`, and the predicate after `僕も` is omitted.

Comment: Hi, to be clear, when you say "the predicate after 僕も is omitted", are you referring to だ ?

Comment: @Pacerier No. 映画スター is omitted from 彼は映画スターであり、僕も映画スターだ.

Comment: ic =D, Just a quick question: is である both a 連体形 and a 終止形 of the copula だ ?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. The ある is both the rentaikee and shuushikee; since it is a verb, there is no disctinction in present Japanese. However, when it is contracted, the rentaikee is な and the shuushikee is だ. This part is mysterious.

Comment: ok thx for the info =)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment in the comment section since I just joined, but the usual way of saying this would probably be 「映画スターだけではなく or だけじゃなくて、政治家もしている」. People often use 「する」 to talk about jobs. Also, 「であり」 is formal written style and would sound strange in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds odd. How about:

> 彼は俳優で、また政治家でもある。

Yeah, I don't like the word 映画スター too much.