# Why does replacing だ to である changes the meaning of a the sentence?

Tags: grammar, copula

1. 「彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ。」 means "He is a movie star, and a politician is a movie star, too" <sub>(from Tsuyoshi's comment below [this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2890/264))</sub>
2. 「彼は映画スターであり、政治家でもある。」 means "He is a movie star and also a politician." <sub>[(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Quantity_and_extents:_.E3.81.A8_to.2C_.E3.82.82_mo.2C_.E3.81.8B_ka.2C_.E3.82.84_ya.2C_.E3.81.8B.E3.82.89_kara.2C_.E3.81.BE.E3.81.A7_made)</sub>

If we were to replace だ with である in (1), we have: 「彼は映画スターであり、政治家もである」. [Sawa suggests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/is-this-grammatical/2900#2900) that で has to be attached to a noun for a sentence to be grammatical, so after swapping the positions of も and で, we have: 「彼は映画スターであり、政治家でもある」.

What I cannot understand is why does replacing だ to である (and applying the necessary で and も swap) changes the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: The も・で swap isn't ‘necessary’. Rather もで and でも mean different things, but もで is considered ungrammatical (for some reason), so you only see でも.

Comment: @Zhen: Both もだ and もである are grammatical, and have the same meaning, just like だ and である.  (でもある has a different meaning, as you stated.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Yeah, but もで on its own just feels very strange to me. もである is perhaps better analysed as も plus である taken as a verb, and so the て-form of that construction ought to be もで... but it just sounds weird.

Comment: @Zhen: I do not find もで strange, and I am not sure why you do.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the help, I'd finally got it =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding where the difference is.

> 彼は映画スターであり、政治家もだ。

There are two は in this sentence: 彼は and 政治家は, but the latter is hidden behind も.  You thus have the following: 彼は映画スターである and 政治家も映画スターである。

> 彼は映画スターであり、政治家でもある

There is only one は in this sentence: 彼は, but there are two "である", the latter being augmented with a も.  You thus have the following: 彼は映画スターである and 彼は政治家で(も)ある。.

To sum up: もである is different from でもある.  It's not the だ/である that makes the difference.